# Is it possible to check wether user giving (Rating and Review) or not in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, app-store, rating

I have to check if user given a Rating and Review from my app to appstore.

If once user given a (Rating and Review) in the App Store, once this done it should ask to rate app again.

Comment: There is no way to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can not check from apple side. because apple development not provide any API to check the user is given a rating and review because there is not any public id or api. but you can check from your app is user open the app rating prompt or not.

Check the [Appirater](https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater) that manage the app rate prompt but that manage locally once you make a rate option selection or dont want rating option selection that wont appear again.

Comment: Thanks for given a comment. Without Appirater also we can manage no locally.

Comment: we can without appirater i just attached that for your knowlage. check its class how does that manage:P